# Laravel Filter Many to Many Relationship with whereIn array values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I the following scenario:
I have a listings and locations tables. A category has many locations and a listing can belong to many locations (many to many relationship). Here is how my models look like:

Table structure for listings

- id,
- name,
- time_stamps

Listing Model (App\Models\Listing)

```
public function locations() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Location', 'listing_locations', 
          'listing_id', 'location_id');
    }
```

Table structure for locations

- id,
- name,
- timestamps

Location Model (App\Models\Location)

```
public function listings() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Listing', 'listing_locations', 
          'location_id', 'listing_id');
    }
```

Pivot table (listing_locations) structure:

- id,
- listing_id,
- location_id

Everything works fine - I can get listings with their locations and vice versa. The problems sets in when I want to filter the listings - I want to only get listings which belong to particular locations (the locations are in an array coming from a front end). One problem I have is the location names in the database are Google map location names e.g 207-192 Spadina Ave, Toronto, ON M5T 2C2, Canada but user is only filtering with Canada so I have to use like.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$listings = Listing::where('id', '>', 0);

    $countries = $request->query('countries');
    
                foreach ($countries as $country) {
                    $conditions[] = ['name', 'like', '%' . $country . '%'];
                }
    
                
                $listings->whereHas('location', function($q) use ($conditions) {
                    $q->where($conditions);
                });
```

However, this only works when the countries array (filter) has only one value.
I have also tried using orWhere but this does not apply the filter.

Have also tried this

```
$listings->whereHas('location', function($q) use ($countries) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($countries); $i++){
                    $q->orwhere('name', 'like',  '%' . $countries[$i] .'%');
                } 
            });
```

but does not work.

Any idea how this should work?

Comment: what you get in  dd($countries) ?

Comment: @JohnLobo dd($countries) has all selected countries in an array
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Spain"
  1 => "Taiwan"
]

Comment: if its exact word of country then you can use wherein

Comment: Not exact work ... thus the need of applying LIKE % $country %

Comment: whats the issue of second query

Comment: try this $listings->when(count($countries),function ($query)use ($countries) {

            $query->whereHas('location', function($q) use ($countries) {
                foreach ($countries as $country) {
                    $q->orWhere('name', 'like',  '%' .$country .'%');
                }
            });

        });

Comment: Yours (as well as my second query) returns all the data i.e it does not filter by the provided countries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234684/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-benjamin-mwendwa-munyoki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group multiple where conditions using where callback

```
 $listings->when(count($countries),function ($query)use ($countries) {
        
         $query->whereHas('location', function($q) use ($countries) {
            $q->where( function($q) use ($countries) {
                foreach ($countries as $country) {
                  $q->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $country . '%');
               }
            });
        });
        
});
```